# Trying to show database fields in <select>

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

I am trying to show DB fields within a select and option field

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","cl49-XXX","XXX");
if (!$con) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("cl49-XXX", $con)or die( "Unable to select database");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories")or die('You need enter a catagory ' );
echo "<tr>"; // first row beginning
for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result); $i++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $category= $row['category'];
    echo "<option>$category'
       ";
    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
        echo "</option><option>"; // it's time no move to next row
    }
}
echo ""; // last row ending
?>
```

Why is my  not showing any fields?

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: i have fixed it now, typical!

Comment: When the time allows for it, you can answer your own question. This way anyone else experiencing a similar issue can try your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo "</option><option>";`

why do you have 2 `<option>` tags? Use only the closing tag

```
echo `</option>`
```